# Get object rotation (or any property) in a frame_change_pre handler while rendering

Tags: scripting

I'm using the `frame_change_pre` handler to get an object rotation and write it down on a text object. It works ferpectly in the playback, but not in render. I assume that's because while rendering the GUI is not updating.

So, how can I get such values in render time?

Comment: In short you want to use the evaluated dependency graph which you can access in the `frame_change_post` handler.

Comment: Yep, it works :-) Sorry for the dup, and thanks!